# Iterating over lists of lists in Python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a list of lists:

```
lst1 = [["(a)", "(b)", "(c)"],["(d)", "(e)", "(f)", "(g)"]]
```

I want to iterate over each element and perform some string operations on them for example:

```
replace("(", "")
```

I tried iterating over the list using:

```
for l1 in lst1:
   for i in l1:
       lst2.append(list(map(str.replace("(", ""), l1)))
```

I wanted the out result to be the same as original list of lists but without the parenthesis. Also, I am looking for a method in editing lists of lists and not really a specific solution to this question.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did what you did, i used the fact that each element of a list can be assigned a new (or updated) value:

```
>>> lst1 = [["(a)", "(b)", "(c)"],["(d)", "(e)", "(f)", "(g)"]]
>>> for x in range(len(lst1)):
        for y in range(len(lst1[x])):
            lst1[x][y] = lst1[x][y].replace("(", "")
>>> lst1
[['a)', 'b)', 'c)'], ['d)', 'e)', 'f)', 'g)']]
```

**EDIT**

This is how you do it with the "real problem" that you mentioned in the comment:

```
a = [[(12.22, 12.122, 0.000)], [(1232.11, 123.1231, 0.000)]]
some_num = 10
for x in range(len(a)):
    b = list(a[x][0])
    for y in range(len(b)):
        b[y] *= some_num
    a[x] = tuple(b)
print(a)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[(122.2, 121.22, 0.0), (12321.099999999999, 1231.231, 0.0)]
```

^ All elements have been multiplied by a number and the original format is kept

This is how it works:

So you have the initial list 'a' that has two sublists each with only ONE element (the tuple that contains the x,y,z coordinates). I go through list 'a' and make the tuples a list and set them equal to 'b' (so the fourth line has a value of [12.22, 12.122, 0.000] the first time around (and the next tuple (as a list) the next time around).

Then I go through each of the elements in 'b' (the tuple converted into a list) and multiply each element in that tuple by a number with the use of the increment operator (+=, -=, /=, *=). Once this loop is done, I set that same position in the master list 'a' equal to the tuple of the previously converted tuple. < If this doesn't make sense, what I'm saying is that the initial tuples are converted into lists (then operated on), and then converter back to tuples (since you want it to end up with the same format as before).

Hope this helps!

Comment: you could use `for L in lst1: for i, x in enumerate(L): L[i] = x.replace("(", "")` instead of `range()`

Comment: yes, you are correct, there are many ways to do this problem, i just answered it in his way of thinking. Personally, i would've done it the way @user3263488 did it

Comment: On my previous comment, I meant the user @iCodez

Comment: @Ol'Reliable this is working very well. Can you break it down step by step for me? I know this is asking a lot but i want to understand what is happening in every part of the code not just copy your solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: `range(0, len(lst1))` is redundant, `range(len(lst1))` is enough

Comment: Yes, this looks pretty good. I am wondering why this method doesn't work on a list like this: a = [[[(12, 12, 12)],[(13, 13, 13)],[(15, 15, 15)]], [[(12, 12, 12)],[(13, 13, 13)],[(15, 15, 15)]]] it only performs the operation on the first list and it's sub list, but not on the second and any other following it.

Comment: it looks like the line: b = list(a[x][0]) is what is making it only iterate over the first list. How can i add a variable there instead of index number zero?

Comment: Because you have a list inside of a list inside of a list. My code should solve for structures like you example: [[(12.22, 12.122, 0.000)], [(1232.11, 123.1231, 0.000)]], which is a list inside of a list only.

Comment: is there no easy way to change the structure of the data because it seems like this is very inefficient because each of your elements is a tuple INSIDE of a list.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:**

Yes, you should use normal for-loops if you want to:

1. Preform multiple operations on each item contained in each sub-list.
2. Keep both the main list as well as the sub-lists as the same objects.

Below is a simple demonstration of how to do this:

```
main = [["(a)", "(b)", "(c)"], ["(d)", "(e)", "(f)", "(g)"]]

print id(main)
print id(main[0])
print id(main[1])
print

for sub in main:
    for index,item in enumerate(sub):

        ### Preform operations ###
        item = item.replace("(", "")
        item = item.replace(")", "")
        item *= 2

        sub[index] = item  # Reassign the item

print main
print
print id(main)
print id(main[0])
print id(main[1])
```

Output:

```
25321880
25321600
25276288

[['aa', 'bb', 'cc'], ['dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg']]

25321880
25321600
25276288
```

---

Use a [nested list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lst1 = [["(a)", "(b)", "(c)"],["(d)", "(e)", "(f)", "(g)"]]
>>> id(lst1)
35863808
>>> lst1[:] = [[y.replace("(", "") for y in x] for x in lst1]
>>> lst1
[['a)', 'b)', 'c)'], ['d)', 'e)', 'f)', 'g)']]
>>> id(lst1)
35863808
>>>
```

The `[:]` will keep the list object the same.

Comment: yes, list comprehensions are useful for this if you just want to make a one liner. Although you are technically still using a nested for loop, my soln. is the correct answer based on how @user3263488 was thinking

Comment: @Ol'Reliable - Well, I'll add a solution that uses normal for-loops.  The nested list comprehension one though should work fine in most cases.

Comment: I like this approach. Now a real problem. I want to take a different list. one with XYZ coordinates like this: [[(12.22, 12.122, 0.000)], [(1232.11, 123.1231, 0.000)]]. Is there a way to nest a few operations? I want to strip it of parenthesis and commas then multiply each coordinate by a number and put it back together like it was. Any ideas?

Comment: this is probably why i wanted to use a for loop since i can perform multiple operations in a row. right?

Comment: what do you mean by "strip it of ... commas"? You still need commas for the elements

Comment: @user3263488 - Yes, you should use a for-loop if you want to preform multiple operations.  Do you want the sub-lists to remain the same, or just the main list?

Comment: yes i want to keep the data output format same as input was originally.

Comment: It's easy to do multiple things with list comprehensions as long as you're mucking with each item independently. In general, you can write `[[some_crazy_operation(x) for x in l1] for l1 in lst1]` where `some_crazy_operation` is a function that does whatever you want with each input and returns the new value you want in its place.

Note that what we're doing with this solution is actually transforming an existing list of lists into a new list of new lists, instead of editing in place, so there may be performance drawbacks for the simplicity of this approach.

Comment: @user3263488 if you want to perform multiple operations on items in sub-list, just wrap them up in function, so they become one operation ;)

Comment: why do you use `for index,_ in enumerate(sub)` instead of `for index, item in enumerate(sub)`?

Comment: Good idea.  I missed that for some reason. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> lst1 = [["(a)", "(b)", "(c)"],["(d)", "(e)", "(f)", "(g)"]]
>>> [[j.strip('()') for j in i] for i in lst1]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']]
>>> [[j.lstrip('(') for j in i] for i in lst1]
[['a)', 'b)', 'c)'], ['d)', 'e)', 'f)', 'g)']]
```